# CannotVerifyCopySource when copying a file from one datalake container (A) to another datalake container(B) within the same azure storage account

Tags: azure-storage-account

Tried to copy a file from one datalake container (A) to another datalake container(B) using java azure sdk but ended with the following error.

Error: `CannotVerifyCopySource`Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header when copying a blob from one container to another **within the same storage account**.

I thought I can able to copy a file from one container to another container if "Storage Blob Data Contributor" role added to the storage account scope. Any idea what I am doing wrong. By the way, copy blob works if my storage account has "blob public access".

Here are the information about the storage account and the containers.

1. Storage account got created recently (It just a day older)
2. Both containers exist within the same storage account.
3. Public access disabled on that storage account.
4. Assigned "Storage Blob Data Contributor" to the storage account (Scoped to storage account).
5. I used **shared access signature** which is generated from azure portal (and it is valid) from the storage account level.
6. I tried with storage account access keys as well.

Here are the information about the azure java sdk and api

1. Method used: copyFromUrlWithResponse from com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient
2. Using java sdk azure-storage-file-datalake of version 12.15.0.
3. The blob which I am trying to copy "exists" in the source container (A).

Answer (score 0):

> Error: `**CannotVerifyCopySource**`Server failed to authenticate the request. Please refer to the information in the www-authenticate header when copying a blob from one container to another **within the same storage account**.

The above error may occur whether there are any firewall or network issues that might be blocking the authentication process.

***Portal -> storageaccount -> networking -> Firewalls and virtual networks -> Enabled from all networks***

**Portal:**
[image]

Initially, I got the same error like as same as you. I checked the networking is in enabled selected networks.

After assigning to **`enabled from all networks`**. I used the sample code to copy from one container to another container.

**Code:**

```
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobContainerClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClient;
import com.azure.storage.blob.BlobServiceClientBuilder;
import com.azure.identity.*;

public class App {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String Endpoint="your-storage-endpoint";
        BlobServiceClient blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClientBuilder()
        .endpoint(Endpoint)
        .credential(new DefaultAzureCredentialBuilder().build())
        .buildClient();
        BlobContainerClient blobContainerClient =  blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("filesystem1");
        BlobContainerClient destContainerClient =  blobServiceClient.getBlobContainerClient("filesystem2");
        BlobClient dst = destContainerClient.getBlobClient("demo.mp4");
        BlobClient src = blobContainerClient.getBlobClient("sample.mp4");
        dst.beginCopy(src.getBlobUrl(), null); 
        System.out.println("The file is copied from one container to another container successfully"); 
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
The file is copied from one container to another container successfully
```

[image]

**Portal:**
[image]

Further, if you need to copy behind the firewall you can refer to this [Ms-document](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/updates/copy-blob-support-over-private-endpoints/) more in detail.